# Stream Corrupted Exception

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a client/server program using sockets. The client first sends the file name and the server reads the file from hard disk and sends back to the client through socket. Finally the client writes the content into a file. When I run the code a `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header` error is returned.

Client code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ClientSocket {

    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.8.17.218";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 5000;

    String fileName;
    String ip;

    Socket socket;
    Message msg=null,message=null;

    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;

    ObjectOutputStream toFile=null;

    File destFile;

    public ClientSocket(String ipi,String fname){
            fileName = fname;
            ip=ipi;
            msg=new Message(fileName);
         destFile=new File("C:\\DestinationDirectory",fileName);

        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to server: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

     while(true){
            try {
                 if (out == null) {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                  }

                out.writeObject(msg);
                out.flush();

                //get the reply from the server
                if (in == null) {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                }
                message = (Message) in.readObject();
                //System.out.println("Server said: " + message.getMessage());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            }

        try {
            toFile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));
            toFile.writeObject(message);
            System.out.println(message.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       ClientSocket cs= new ClientSocket("10.8.17.218","build.sql");

     }
}
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerFile {
    private static final int PORT = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Message message=null,toOut=null;
        try {
            //Creates a new server socket with the given port number
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occured while creating the server socket");
            return;
        }

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            //Waits untill a connection is made, and returns that socket
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occured while accepting the socket");
            return;
        }
        //Now we have established the a connection with the client
        System.out.println("Connection created, client IP: " + socket.getInetAddress());
        ObjectInputStream in = null,fromFile=null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null,tempOut=null;
        File sourceFile;

        FileInputStream from=null;
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        String name=null;
        while(true){
            try {
                if (in == null) {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                }
                 message= (Message) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("Client said: " + message.getMessage());
                name=message.getMessage();
                sourceFile=new File("D:\\temp\\",name);

                name="D:\\temp\\"+name;
                System.out.println(name);

                from=new FileInputStream("D:/temp/build.sql");
                bis=new BufferedInputStream(from);
                fromFile=new ObjectInputStream(bis);
                toOut=(Message) fromFile.readObject();
                //Send a reply to the client
                if (out == null) {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                }
                out.writeObject(toOut);
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `ObjectInputStream` per transaction in the server, yet you're using a single `ObjectOutputStream` in the client. You should use exactly one of each at both ends for the life of the socket.